# How to fix "HttpMessageNotWritableException" exception in Spring 5.1.5 in simple api call

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-rest

I'm using Spring 5.1.5 version and making a simple rest call. But getting HttpMessageNotWritableException No converter found for return value of type: class com.testRestApp.models.Employee.

I have made a similar call with Spring Rest 4.3.18 and it is working over there. Not sure if it version issue. I tried a couple of solution like updating Jackson's version (currently I'm using version 2.9.7 ), updating Apache tomcat version to 8.5 and java to 8.
I have gone through the code also and fine that this exception usually came when HttpMessageConverter.write(T,MediaType, HttpOutputMessage) method fails.
but not able to understand the root cause of this exception. 
Also tried to put the request mapping at class level as well as method level but still getting the same issue.

Initially I was facing xsd schema version issue also which later resolved by removing version no from schema location. (Not sure if this can be reason of this exception ).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class HelloWorld {   

 @Autowired
 EmployeeService empService;

 @RequestMapping(value="emp/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public Employee getEmployee() {
    return empService.getEmployee();
 }

}
```

//Service class

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
 @Autowired
 Employee emp;  
 public EmployeeService() {
 }  
 public Employee getEmployee() {
    emp = new Employee();
    emp.setName("test1");
    emp.setDesignation("SD");
    emp.setExp(2);
    return emp;
 }
}
```

//Model with getters and setters

```
@Component
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private String designation;
  private int exp;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>         
 <springframework.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
 <jackson.library>2.9.7</jackson.library>
</properties
    <!-- Spring Rest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.finebooker.models.Employee
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:233)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: It clearly says that it is unable to convert into class com.finebooker.models.Employee class, do you have two Employee classes with different packages ?

Comment: Thanks Sambit for your quick response and pointing out this mistake. However, even after removing one of the Employee model, still getting the same exception. Please let me know if you need configuration file also.

Comment: I would suggest to write simple standalone program to generate the json using jackson with the employee class. It will give you the proper direction.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sambit. I'll definitely look into your suggestion. However, issue is fixed now, as I missed one configuration due to which some classes were not registered and container was not able to convert json format over Http.